# Can one board a flight with photo ID bearing an old last name?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, regulations, paperwork, driving-licenses

I bought a flight reservation for my mother, not knowing that she never got a drivers license with her new married last name. She has a drivers license with her old last name. The reservation has the new married last name. Will she be allowed to board if she produces her marriage certificate showing the name change from the name on the driver's license *to* the name on the reservation?

Update: she's in the US, flying with Spirit Airlines

Comment: And where is going to? If it's not domestic you will have problems clearing border control without a valid passport.

Comment: Depends what country and what airline - see [Does any airline in the world allow air travel without government identification?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35015/does-any-airline-in-the-world-allow-air-travel-without-government-identification) for some examples of where no government ID is needed so there'd be no problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some airlines, like [American Airlines](http://www.aa.com/i18n/agency/Booking_Ticketing/Ticketing/Name_Change_Restrictions.jsp) or [Delta](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/agency/useful-resources/name-correction-policy.html) allow name changes before the flight. Firstly, you should check with the carrier if (and how) can you correct your mother's name. If it is not possible, she should bring her marriage certificate along with other documents that show her maiden name and her married name. [Here](http://gogreentravelgreen.com/change-your-name-on-an-airline-ticket-lessons-learned/) you can check a real history (and some tips) from a just married traveler. She had no problem traveling with a ticket printed with her maiden name.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to skip the guessing game and call the airline to explain the situation as fast as possible.

If they will not accept her as is, they might be able to come up with a solution for her.

Comment: Worth a shot, even if Spirit is infamous for aggressively bad customer service...