# Why does typically nobody check whether one picked up one's own luggage at the airport's luggage claim area?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, lost-luggage

Airports have many checks, but typically none in the luggage claim area. Why does typically nobody check whether one picked up one's own luggage (and not somebody else's or forgetting one's luggage) at the airport's luggage claim area? I'm curious if the reason is simply that there's no need for that, and/or is motivated by the desire to save airport's money or passenger's time, or some other reason.

Related: [Data on baggage theft rates, by airport or airline](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/36751/1810)

---

**Close voters:** this isn't at all opinion-based, airport authorities most likely have made some statements about and/or released statistics, and there are plenty of research papers on airports e.g. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jairtraman.2004.09.004

Comment: There are some airports/airlines which check more frequently. I remember the time I lost my receipt, in "nowhere" in Russia (so I could also not talk with locals). In general, it seems that in small airports check are more frequent (bored people, looking for small talk?), but I had your exact question often.

Comment: I have also wondered at least why not more luggage is stolen in the pickup area. I guess the chances for being caught are simply to high. If you snitch an arbitrary bag from the conveyor belt, the chances are pretty high that the real owner is nearby waiting for his luggage and will see what you are doing.

Comment: I imagine the probability of stealing luggage with high value items also isn't great. People will likely take those in their carry-on or pay for more secure shipping.

Comment: I have heard that in some airports you can even walk into the luggage pick-up area from outside.

Comment: @Willeke In the US, that's generally true for domestic flights.

Comment: I've been to a place or two where they checked the luggage tags against the claim number at the exit. Can't remember exactly where, probably Asia somewhere.

Comment: I could have sworn this has been asked before. Related question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44226/how-to-deter-theft-of-checked-baggage-at-baggage-carousels

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it true that people "can just take all the luggage off the airport conveyer belt and leave with it."?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44211/is-it-true-that-people-can-just-take-all-the-luggage-off-the-airport-conveyer-b)

Answer (score 16):

"Bang for the buck" mostly.

In the US you can certainly walk into any airport's domestic arrival area and grab any bag you like.  Apparently it's not enough of a problem to warrant any type of control

1. Generally you would end up with a beaten-up bag or suitcase and a lot of dirty laundry that won't fit you. That's not a particularly attractive target.
2. The chance of getting caught is quite high. Since there is no customs or immigration, passengers are typically faster than the bags.
3. Cost and complexity of the control is high. You would need to fundamentally change the layout and gate off the baggage claim area and staff tag controls. It's probably a lot cheaper to just compensate the passenger for the few stolen bags.

Comment: The baggage claim area is often under CCTV surveillance too, and periodically in the US the airport police catches someone for theft, which helps prevent anyone from making a career out of it.

Comment: did you mean no customs and immigration?

Comment: Immigration is between getting off the plane and collecting luggage, customs after collecting luggage. But only on international flights.

Comment: Sorry, the note about immigratioin was a typo. On international arrivals it's possible that your bags are on the belt before you get there since immigration can be slow, but for domestic arrivals that's rare.