# Why are there ashtrays in the bathrooms on nonsmoking flights?

Tags: security, aircraft, smoking

Airplane bathroom:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

- Why are there ashtrays in the bathrooms on nonsmoking flights?

Comment: As covered in [this great talk - What Programmers can learn from Pilots about 18 minutes in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=we4G_X91e5w), Lavatory Ashtrays are required for a 747 to be valid to take off, but weather radar isn't!

Comment: As a cabin crew member, we use it when we deliver empty planes (ferry flights) because we smoke in these flights because no one is seeing us.. we do nasty things on planes when there are no passengers ;) :D

Comment: I'd always presumed these were left over from before smoking was banned on planes!

Comment: related reading: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5224/are-there-any-airlines-that-still-allow-smoking-on-board-flights?rq=1

Comment: @CGCampbell how should I attribute it to myself, then?

Comment: @user3306356 I'm not sure why you removed the attributions I added. If you took the photos, their copyright is yours. Images need to be attributed. I'll find the main StackExchange meta question where it is discussed.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[Asked and answered on Aviation.SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9505/why-do-lavatories-in-modern-planes-still-have-ash-trays/9510#9510).

Summary: They're required by US federal aviation regulations. The apparent rationale is: a desperate, or unscrupulous, smoker might (illegally) light a cigarette in the lavatory. If they do, it is good for there to be somewhere safe for them to put the cigarette butt. Otherwise, if they don't see anywhere else to put it, they might put it in the trash receptacle, which is full of combustible paper and could start a dangerous fire.

There is speculation that the [1973 crash of Varig Flight 820](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varig_Flight_820) may have been caused by just such a fire.

Comment: I feel like it's like telling kids: don't do drugs but here's clean needles just in case

Comment: @user3306356 The hazards afforded by sharing needles are oft worse than the drugs in the first place. Similarly here the hazard of a fire is much worse than someone having a quick fag.

Comment: This is called 'harm reduction' when related to drugs.

Comment: @user Indeed, that is not an uncommon public-health policy. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needle_exchange_programme -- plenty of cities have determined that people will do drugs even without clean needles and it's better if those people don't get AIDS.

Comment: @user3306356 if you find a kid that's like "I don't really wanna do drugs" and then you're like "if you ever do, here is a clean needle" and then he is like "well, then, I don't see why I wouldn't do drugs, now that I have a clean needle. That is really the thing that is inciting me to do so.", that kid has problems.

Comment: @user3306356 I would relate it more to the availability of ambulances even though people aren't senseless enough to do things which requires a trip in one. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Having worked for a Government contractor, I can tell you first hand that it is very expensive to make a design change, even a trivial one like removing ashtrays that are no longer needed.  I cannot tell you how many times I've seen piping being re-routed around obstructions that no longer exist.  The reason was that the cost of reworking all of the drawings, re-engineering the design, and getting all necessary approvals costs far more than just continuing with the unnecessary work.  Generally, material is far cheaper than labor.

The "just in case someone decides to smoke" explanation seems plausible, but sounds more like an afterthought to me.  I think the likely reason, like most everything else, is money.  The cost of installing an unnecessary ashtray in a new airplane is orders of magnitude cheaper than paying all of those people to remove it from the airplane's design.  This does not even consider the cost incurred by the FAA to update all of their regulations.

Comment: new planes are designed with ashtrays too. The A380, for example.